# Simplexml not using html entities

Tags: php, simplexml

I am currently having issues trying to get an html entity to show a double quote as `&quot;`

As of right now, it doesn't generate it.

Output

```
<name>2nd Platoon "Viking" </name>
```

PHP code

```
function GetPlayerID($id)
{
    include('../../config/db.php');
    $mysqliDebug = 1;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM players WHERE id=$id ORDER BY id ASC";
    $results = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        if(!$results and $mysqliDebug) {
           echo '<div style="margin-top:10px" class="alert alert-danger">There was an error in query:'. $results.'</div>';
           echo $con->error;
        }
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results))
    {
        return $row['playerid'];
    }
}


$result = file_get_contents('../21st.json');
$json = json_decode($result,true);
$file = 'viking.xml';
$patch = 'viking.paa';
$str = '&quot;Viking&quot;';


$tags = $json['tags'];
$TOC = $json['tags']['1092531']['users'];
$RRDLead = $json['tags']['1656129']['users'];
$RRD = $json['tags']['1518730']['users'];
$GLead = $json['tags']['1217502']['users'];
$Guardian = $json['tags']['1217510']['users'];
$NLead = $json['tags']['1167334']['users'];
$Nightmare = $json['tags']['1065783']['users'];
$VLead = $json['tags']['1167327']['users'];
$Viking = $json['tags']['1065785']['users'];
$WLead = $json['tags']['1167327']['users'];
$Whiskey = $json['tags']['1065786']['users'];



$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<!DOCTYPE squad SYSTEM "squad.dtd"><squad/>');
$xml->addAttribute('nick', '2nd');
$xml->addChild('name', '2nd Platoon '. htmlspecialchars("\"Viking\" "));
$xml->addChild('email','21stusarmyrangers@gmail.com');
$xml->addChild('web','http://21starmyrangers.enjin.com/viking');
$xml->addChild('picture', 'viking.paa');
$xml->addChild('title','2nd Platoon &quot;Viking&quot; / 21st Ranger Regiment');
$first = true;
foreach ( $Viking as $userId )
{


        $user = isset($json['users'][$userId]) ? $json['users'][$userId] : null;

        $tags = [];

        if ($user) 
        {
            $tags = array_filter($json['tags'], function($tag) use ($userId) {
                return in_array($userId, $tag['users']);
            });
        }
        // break;
        $tagIds = array_keys($tags);
        // echo htmlspecialchars(htmlspecialchars($user['username']));
        foreach ( $tagIds as $tag )
        {

                $member = $xml->addChild('member');
                if ($tag == 1065758)
                {
                    $member->addAttribute('id', GetPlayerID($userId));
                    $member->addAttribute('nick', 'PV2 ' . htmlspecialchars($user['username']));
                    $member->addChild('name', htmlspecialchars($user['username']));
                    $member->addChild('email', 'N/A');
                    $member->addChild('icq', 'N/A');
                    $member->addChild('remark', 'N/A');
                    break;
                }
                elseif ($tag == 1065759)
                {
                    $member->addAttribute('id', GetPlayerID($userId));
                    $member->addAttribute('nick', 'PFC ' . htmlspecialchars($user['username']));
                    $member->addChild('name', htmlspecialchars($user['username']));
                    $member->addChild('email', 'N/A');
                    $member->addChild('icq', 'N/A');
                    $member->addChild('remark', 'N/A');
                    break;
                }
                elseif ($tag == 1065760)
                {
                    $member->addAttribute('id', GetPlayerID($userId));
                    $member->addAttribute('nick', 'SPC ' . htmlspecialchars($user['username']));
                    $member->addChild('name', htmlspecialchars($user['username']));
                    $member->addChild('email', 'N/A');
                    $member->addChild('icq', 'N/A');
                    $member->addChild('remark', 'N/A');
                    break;
                }
                elseif ($tag == 1065762)
                {
                    $member->addAttribute('id', GetPlayerID($userId));
                    $member->addAttribute('nick', 'CPL ' . htmlspecialchars($user['username']));
                    $member->addChild('name', htmlspecialchars($user['username']));
                    $member->addChild('email', 'N/A');
                    $member->addChild('icq', 'N/A');
                    $member->addChild('remark', 'N/A');
                    break;
                }
                elseif ($tag == 1065763)
                {
                    $member->addAttribute('id', GetPlayerID($userId));
                    $member->addAttribute('nick', 'SGT ' . htmlspecialchars($user['username']));
                    $member->addChild('name', htmlspecialchars($user['username']));
                    $member->addChild('email', 'N/A');
                    $member->addChild('icq', 'N/A');
                    $member->addChild('remark', 'N/A');
                    break;
                }
                elseif ($tag == 1065764)
                {
                    $member->addAttribute('id', GetPlayerID($userId));
                    $member->addAttribute('nick', 'SSG ' . htmlspecialchars($user['username']));
                    $member->addChild('name', htmlspecialchars($user['username']));
                    $member->addChild('email', 'N/A');
                    $member->addChild('icq', 'N/A');
                    $member->addChild('remark', 'N/A');
                    break;
                }
                elseif ($tag == 1065871)
                {
                    $member->addAttribute('id', GetPlayerID($userId));
                    $member->addAttribute('nick', 'SFC ' . htmlspecialchars($user['username']));
                    $member->addChild('name', htmlspecialchars($user['username']));
                    $member->addChild('email', 'N/A');
                    $member->addChild('icq', 'N/A');
                    $member->addChild('remark', 'N/A');
                    break;
                }
                elseif ($tag == 1065765)
                {
                    $member->addAttribute('id', GetPlayerID($userId));
                    $member->addAttribute('nick', 'MSG ' . htmlspecialchars($user['username']));
                    $member->addChild('name', htmlspecialchars($user['username']));
                    $member->addChild('email', 'N/A');
                    $member->addChild('icq', 'N/A');
                    $member->addChild('remark', 'N/A');
                    break;
                }
                elseif ($tag == 1065766)
                {
                    $member->addAttribute('id', GetPlayerID($userId));
                    $member->addAttribute('nick', '1SG ' . htmlspecialchars($user['username']));
                    $member->addChild('name', htmlspecialchars($user['username']));
                    $member->addChild('email', 'N/A');
                    $member->addChild('icq', 'N/A');
                    $member->addChild('remark', 'N/A');
                    break;
                }
                elseif ($tag == 1065767)
                {
                    $member->addAttribute('id', GetPlayerID($userId));
                    $member->addAttribute('nick', 'SGM ' . htmlspecialchars($user['username']));
                    $member->addChild('name', htmlspecialchars($user['username']));
                    $member->addChild('email', 'N/A');
                    $member->addChild('icq', 'N/A');
                    $member->addChild('remark', 'N/A');
                    break;
                }
                elseif ($tag == 1065768)
                {
                    $member->addAttribute('id', GetPlayerID($userId));
                    $member->addAttribute('nick', 'WO1 ' . htmlspecialchars($user['username']));
                    $member->addChild('name', htmlspecialchars($user['username']));
                    $member->addChild('email', 'N/A');
                    $member->addChild('icq', 'N/A');
                    $member->addChild('remark', 'N/A');
                    break;
                }
                elseif ($tag == 1065769)
                {
                    $member->addAttribute('id', GetPlayerID($userId));
                    $member->addAttribute('nick', 'CW2 ' . htmlspecialchars($user['username']));
                    $member->addChild('name', htmlspecialchars($user['username']));
                    $member->addChild('email', 'N/A');
                    $member->addChild('icq', 'N/A');
                    $member->addChild('remark', 'N/A');
                    break;
                }
                elseif ($tag == 1065771)
                {
                    $member->addAttribute('id', GetPlayerID($userId));
                    $member->addAttribute('nick', 'CW3 ' . htmlspecialchars($user['username']));
                    $member->addChild('name', htmlspecialchars($user['username']));
                    $member->addChild('email', 'N/A');
                    $member->addChild('icq', 'N/A');
                    $member->addChild('remark', 'N/A');
                    break;
                }
                elseif ($tag == 1065772)
                {
                    $member->addAttribute('id', GetPlayerID($userId));
                    $member->addAttribute('nick', 'CW4 ' . htmlspecialchars($user['username']));
                    $member->addChild('name', htmlspecialchars($user['username']));
                    $member->addChild('email', 'N/A');
                    $member->addChild('icq', 'N/A');
                    $member->addChild('remark', 'N/A');
                    break;
                }
                elseif ($tag == 1065773)
                {
                    $member->addAttribute('id', GetPlayerID($userId));
                    $member->addAttribute('nick', 'CW5 ' . htmlspecialchars($user['username']));
                    $member->addChild('name', htmlspecialchars($user['username']));
                    $member->addChild('email', 'N/A');
                    $member->addChild('icq', 'N/A');
                    $member->addChild('remark', 'N/A');
                    break;
                }
                elseif ($tag == 1065774)
                {
                    $member->addAttribute('id', GetPlayerID($userId));
                    $member->addAttribute('nick', '2LT ' . htmlspecialchars($user['username']));
                    $member->addChild('name', htmlspecialchars($user['username']));
                    $member->addChild('email', 'N/A');
                    $member->addChild('icq', 'N/A');
                    $member->addChild('remark', 'N/A');
                    break;
                }
                elseif ($tag == 1065776)
                {
                    $member->addAttribute('id', GetPlayerID($userId));
                    $member->addAttribute('nick', '1LT ' . htmlspecialchars($user['username']));
                    $member->addChild('name', htmlspecialchars($user['username']));
                    $member->addChild('email', 'N/A');
                    $member->addChild('icq', 'N/A');
                    $member->addChild('remark', 'N/A');
                    break;
                }
                elseif ($tag == 1085054)
                {
                    $member->addAttribute('id', GetPlayerID($userId));
                    $member->addAttribute('nick', 'MAJ ' . htmlspecialchars($user['username']));
                    $member->addChild('name', htmlspecialchars($user['username']));
                    $member->addChild('email', 'N/A');
                    $member->addChild('icq', 'N/A');
                    $member->addChild('remark', 'N/A');
                    break;
                }
                elseif ($tag == 1234581)
                {
                    $member->addAttribute('id', GetPlayerID($userId));
                    $member->addAttribute('nick', 'LTC ' . htmlspecialchars($user['username']));
                    $member->addChild('name', htmlspecialchars($user['username']));
                    $member->addChild('email', 'N/A');
                    $member->addChild('icq', 'N/A');
                    $member->addChild('remark', 'N/A');
                    break;  
                }
                // break;

        }


}

foreach ( $VLead as $userId )
{


        $user = isset($json['users'][$userId]) ? $json['users'][$userId] : null;

        $tags = [];

        if ($user) 
        {
            $tags = array_filter($json['tags'], function($tag) use ($userId) {
                return in_array($userId, $tag['users']);
            });
        }
        $tagIds = array_keys($tags);
        // echo htmlspecialchars(htmlspecialchars($user['username']));
        foreach ( $tagIds as $tag )
        {

                $member = $xml->addChild('member');
                if ($tag == 1065758)
                {
                    $member->addAttribute('id', GetPlayerID($userId));
                    $member->addAttribute('nick', 'PV2 ' . htmlspecialchars($user['username']));
                    $member->addChild('name', htmlspecialchars($user['username']));
                    $member->addChild('email', 'N/A');
                    $member->addChild('icq', 'N/A');
                    $member->addChild('remark', 'N/A');
                    break;
                }
                elseif ($tag == 1065759)
                {
                    $member->addAttribute('id', GetPlayerID($userId));
                    $member->addAttribute('nick', 'PFC ' . htmlspecialchars($user['username']));
                    $member->addChild('name', htmlspecialchars($user['username']));
                    $member->addChild('email', 'N/A');
                    $member->addChild('icq', 'N/A');
                    $member->addChild('remark', 'N/A');
                    break;
                }
                elseif ($tag == 1065760)
                {
                    $member->addAttribute('id', GetPlayerID($userId));
                    $member->addAttribute('nick', 'SPC ' . htmlspecialchars($user['username']));
                    $member->addChild('name', htmlspecialchars($user['username']));
                    $member->addChild('email', 'N/A');
                    $member->addChild('icq', 'N/A');
                    $member->addChild('remark', 'N/A');
                    break;
                }
                elseif ($tag == 1065762)
                {
                    $member->addAttribute('id', GetPlayerID($userId));
                    $member->addAttribute('nick', 'CPL ' . htmlspecialchars($user['username']));
                    $member->addChild('name', htmlspecialchars($user['username']));
                    $member->addChild('email', 'N/A');
                    $member->addChild('icq', 'N/A');
                    $member->addChild('remark', 'N/A');
                    break;
                }
                elseif ($tag == 1065763)
                {
                    $member->addAttribute('id', GetPlayerID($userId));
                    $member->addAttribute('nick', 'SGT ' . htmlspecialchars($user['username']));
                    $member->addChild('name', htmlspecialchars($user['username']));
                    $member->addChild('email', 'N/A');
                    $member->addChild('icq', 'N/A');
                    $member->addChild('remark', 'N/A');
                    break;
                }
                elseif ($tag == 1065764)
                {
                    $member->addAttribute('id', GetPlayerID($userId));
                    $member->addAttribute('nick', 'SSG ' . htmlspecialchars($user['username']));
                    $member->addChild('name', htmlspecialchars($user['username']));
                    $member->addChild('email', 'N/A');
                    $member->addChild('icq', 'N/A');
                    $member->addChild('remark', 'N/A');
                    break;
                }
                elseif ($tag == 1065871)
                {
                    $member->addAttribute('id', GetPlayerID($userId));
                    $member->addAttribute('nick', 'SFC ' . htmlspecialchars($user['username']));
                    $member->addChild('name', htmlspecialchars($user['username']));
                    $member->addChild('email', 'N/A');
                    $member->addChild('icq', 'N/A');
                    $member->addChild('remark', 'N/A');
                    break;
                }
                elseif ($tag == 1065765)
                {
                    $member->addAttribute('id', GetPlayerID($userId));
                    $member->addAttribute('nick', 'MSG ' . htmlspecialchars($user['username']));
                    $member->addChild('name', htmlspecialchars($user['username']));
                    $member->addChild('email', 'N/A');
                    $member->addChild('icq', 'N/A');
                    $member->addChild('remark', 'N/A');
                    break;
                }
                elseif ($tag == 1065766)
                {
                    $member->addAttribute('id', GetPlayerID($userId));
                    $member->addAttribute('nick', '1SG ' . htmlspecialchars($user['username']));
                    $member->addChild('name', htmlspecialchars($user['username']));
                    $member->addChild('email', 'N/A');
                    $member->addChild('icq', 'N/A');
                    $member->addChild('remark', 'N/A');
                    break;
                }
                elseif ($tag == 1065767)
                {
                    $member->addAttribute('id', GetPlayerID($userId));
                    $member->addAttribute('nick', 'SGM ' . htmlspecialchars($user['username']));
                    $member->addChild('name', htmlspecialchars($user['username']));
                    $member->addChild('email', 'N/A');
                    $member->addChild('icq', 'N/A');
                    $member->addChild('remark', 'N/A');
                    break;
                }
                elseif ($tag == 1065768)
                {
                    $member->addAttribute('id', GetPlayerID($userId));
                    $member->addAttribute('nick', 'WO1 ' . htmlspecialchars($user['username']));
                    $member->addChild('name', htmlspecialchars($user['username']));
                    $member->addChild('email', 'N/A');
                    $member->addChild('icq', 'N/A');
                    $member->addChild('remark', 'N/A');
                    break;
                }
                elseif ($tag == 1065769)
                {
                    $member->addAttribute('id', GetPlayerID($userId));
                    $member->addAttribute('nick', 'CW2 ' . htmlspecialchars($user['username']));
                    $member->addChild('name', htmlspecialchars($user['username']));
                    $member->addChild('email', 'N/A');
                    $member->addChild('icq', 'N/A');
                    $member->addChild('remark', 'N/A');
                    break;
                }
                elseif ($tag == 1065771)
                {
                    $member->addAttribute('id', GetPlayerID($userId));
                    $member->addAttribute('nick', 'CW3 ' . htmlspecialchars($user['username']));
                    $member->addChild('name', htmlspecialchars($user['username']));
                    $member->addChild('email', 'N/A');
                    $member->addChild('icq', 'N/A');
                    $member->addChild('remark', 'N/A');
                    break;
                }
                elseif ($tag == 1065772)
                {
                    $member->addAttribute('id', GetPlayerID($userId));
                    $member->addAttribute('nick', 'CW4 ' . htmlspecialchars($user['username']));
                    $member->addChild('name', htmlspecialchars($user['username']));
                    $member->addChild('email', 'N/A');
                    $member->addChild('icq', 'N/A');
                    $member->addChild('remark', 'N/A');
                    break;
                }
                elseif ($tag == 1065773)
                {
                    $member->addAttribute('id', GetPlayerID($userId));
                    $member->addAttribute('nick', 'CW5 ' . htmlspecialchars($user['username']));
                    $member->addChild('name', htmlspecialchars($user['username']));
                    $member->addChild('email', 'N/A');
                    $member->addChild('icq', 'N/A');
                    $member->addChild('remark', 'N/A');
                    break;
                }
                elseif ($tag == 1065774)
                {
                    $member->addAttribute('id', GetPlayerID($userId));
                    $member->addAttribute('nick', '2LT ' . htmlspecialchars($user['username']));
                    $member->addChild('name', htmlspecialchars($user['username']));
                    $member->addChild('email', 'N/A');
                    $member->addChild('icq', 'N/A');
                    $member->addChild('remark', 'N/A');
                    break;
                }
                elseif ($tag == 1065776)
                {
                    $member->addAttribute('id', GetPlayerID($userId));
                    $member->addAttribute('nick', '1LT ' . htmlspecialchars($user['username']));
                    $member->addChild('name', htmlspecialchars($user['username']));
                    $member->addChild('email', 'N/A');
                    $member->addChild('icq', 'N/A');
                    $member->addChild('remark', 'N/A');
                    break;
                }
                elseif ($tag == 1085054)
                {
                    $member->addAttribute('id', GetPlayerID($userId));
                    $member->addAttribute('nick', 'MAJ ' . htmlspecialchars($user['username']));
                    $member->addChild('name', htmlspecialchars($user['username']));
                    $member->addChild('email', 'N/A');
                    $member->addChild('icq', 'N/A');
                    $member->addChild('remark', 'N/A');
                    break;
                }
                elseif ($tag == 1234581)
                {
                    $member->addAttribute('id', GetPlayerID($userId));
                    $member->addAttribute('nick', 'LTC ' . htmlspecialchars($user['username']));
                    $member->addChild('name', htmlspecialchars($user['username']));
                    $member->addChild('email', 'N/A');
                    $member->addChild('icq', 'N/A');
                    $member->addChild('remark', 'N/A');
                    break;  
                }
                break;

        }


}



$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$doc->loadxml($xml->asXML());
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
foreach( $xpath->query('//*[not(node())]') as $node ) {
    $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}

// $doc->formatOutput = true;
Header('Content-type: text/html charset=UTF-8');
$doc->formatOutput = true;
$xmlString = $doc->saveXML();
echo $xmlString;
$doc->save($file);
```

JSON - https://gist.github.com/Ryahn/ac8fcc8ae77e9a6ee9138e268b592ed3

Comment: have you tried using `htmlspecialchars()`?

Comment: @A.Lau Do you mean htmlentities()? I am already using htmlspecialchars()

Comment: What does it currently do? You should also simplify the code, 500 lines is a lot to look at for a quote/entity issue. I also presume you aren't just viewing the output in a browser..

Comment: Currently it just shows double quotes. I would like it to present `&quot;` in the XML. The line that needs it mostly is `$xml->addChild('name', '2nd Platoon '. htmlspecialchars("\"Viking\" "));` I have tried just using the html entity itself but it does not render in the XML itslef, it converts to double quotes for whatever reason.

Comment: You are viewing the source, or viewing the output in a text editor?

Comment: Viewing the source. I have seen similar XML outputs with the html entity in the source code.

Comment: Can you simplify the code so I can reproduce the issue?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From what you replied, is this what you want?:

```
$string = "\" sdfsd\"";

echo htmlspecialchars(htmlentities($string));
```

output:

```
&quot; sdfsd&quot;
```

Edit (with regards to chris85):

`htmlspecialchars()` could also be replaced with `json_encode()` if & is showing up

Comment: That is double encoding. The output is `&amp;quot; sdfsd&amp;quot;`, not `&quot; sdfsd&quot;`. https://eval.in/639909 I guess the OP wasn't viewing the source...

Comment: @chris85 from his example in the comments, he made a special reference to `htmlspecialchars("\"Viking\" ")` so I just gave him the answer based on that general request.

Comment: Yea, that is/was the correct usage. That would make the double quotes the entity. Your stated `output` is not the actual output, as demonstrated. A browser renders an entity as the character so viewing the output in a browser will not work. If you are seeing `&quot; sdfsd&quot;` using that code then you are viewing the rendered display, not the actual code.. The `&amp;` becomes `&` and then you get the entities name and semicolon.

Comment: @chris85 dunno about that, because I did it in phpfiddle, and that renders html

Comment: Post your PHP fiddle link, or click the link I provided. Here's another version, http://chrisisdoingwhat.com/sample.php. View the page, then the source.

Comment: @chris85 That's interesting. I don't think phpfiddle supports the 'saving' so you'll have to just copy and paste it into it.

Comment: The OPs first example was correct and worked. The OP is viewing the generation incorrectly. You should at least correct the `output` in your answer. https://3v4l.org/fH3Le PHPfiddle, I'd never seen before but it is not correct. In every instance of PHP I've seen this will work as I've stated.